Mismatch in SOAP Request Namespace Prefix and Structure Using Spring Boot and JAXB
I'm working on a Spring Boot project where I need to consume a SOAP web service. I used wsdl2java to generate the client code. However, I'm encountering issues with the generated SOAP request message structure.
Here is the expected SOAP request from SOAP-UI:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:uri="http://uri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <uri:GetPolicy>
         <uri:policyId>12345</uri:policyId>
      </uri:GetPolicy>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

However, my Spring Boot application generates the following SOAP request:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns3:GetPolicy xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.data.org/PolicyServicesLibrary" xmlns:ns3="http://uri.org/" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Serialization/">
            <ns3:policyId>12345</ns3:policyId>
        </ns3:GetPolicy>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

The differences include are as follows, when I am trying I am getting an error because of the incorrect request SOAP payload.

Namespace prefixes (soapenv vs SOAP-ENV).
Additional unnecessary namespaces.

Here's my GetPolicy class:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "policyId"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetPolicy")
public class GetPolicy {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "policyId", namespace = "http://uri.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> policyId;

    public JAXBElement<String> getPolicyId() {
        return policyId;
    }

    public void setPolicyId(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.policyId = value;
    }
}

And, here is the configuration and code where I execute the request:
@Autowired
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
GetPolicy request = factory.createGetPolicy();
request.setPolicyId(factory.createGetPolicyPolicyId("12345"));

webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("SOAP_SERVER_URL");

JAXBElement<GetPolicyResponse> response = (JAXBElement<GetPolicyResponse>) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request, new SoapActionCallback("SOAP_ACTION"));
return response.getValue();

I have also ensured the correct package-level namespace definition in package-info.java:
@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://uri.org/",
    elementFormDefault = jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package my.package.name;

Despite these configurations, the generated SOAP request has the incorrect namespace prefixes and includes additional namespaces. Also, I know that by adding XmlNs I can fix the prefix issue, but I have multiple namespaceURI which should be matched to the same prefix. That's where I stuck with.
Questions:

How can I ensure the generated SOAP request uses soapenv as the namespace prefix instead of SOAP-ENV?
How can I prevent the inclusion of unnecessary namespaces in the
generated SOAP request?

Thank you. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To your first question, to change the namespace prefixes (SOAP-ENV to soapenv) you need to implement the ClientInterceptor and set it to the WebServiceTemplate.
import jakarta.xml.soap.*;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceClientException;
import org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage;

public class Interceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    @SneakyThrows
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        changePrefix(messageContext);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        // if you need to change in the response call the method 'changePrefix' here
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        // if you need to change in the fault response call the method 'changePrefix' here
        return true;
    }

    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception e) throws WebServiceClientException {

    }

    private void changePrefix(MessageContext messageContext) throws SOAPException {
        SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();

        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
        SOAPFault soapFault = soapBody.getFault();

        soapEnvelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(soapEnvelope.getPrefix());
        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soapenv", soapEnvelope.getNamespaceURI());
        soapEnvelope.setPrefix("soapenv");

        if (soapHeader != null) soapHeader.setPrefix("soapenv");
        if (soapBody != null) soapBody.setPrefix("soapenv");
        if (soapFault != null) soapFault.setPrefix("soapenv");
    }
}

To set this to webServiceTemplate you can create a Bean or whatever method you like, add the created interceptor to the new ClientInterceptor[] array,
webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{interceptor});

To your second question yes you can use the package-info.java and add XmlNs when you need to change the other prefixes in the Soap Body for namespaceURI.

Thank you very much for the answer and putting your time to answer for this question.
